# Modeling Items and Options for shopping cart

Tags: mysql, database-design, data-modeling

I am working on a shopping cart application, and I am pretty much stumped on how to model Items and Options according to the following requirements:

1. Each Item may have zero or more Options (color, size, etc)
2. Each Option may have several different values (e.g. green, blue, red, and orange for color)
3. Two Items with the same Option may have different values for that option (e.g. you may order a t-shirt in green or orange, and you may order a ball cap in blue or red)

I'm sure that this is a somewhat common scenario, but it is not one that I have ever faced before. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`item` table (contains the items)

```
item_id
name
```

---

`options` table (contains all options)

```
option_id
name
type -- color, front_color, back_color, size, shoe_size etc.
```

---

`option_value` table (stores all available values per option)

```
option_value_id
option_id
value
```

---

`item_available_option` (stores all available options per item)

```
item_id
option_id
```

---

`item_available_option_value` (stores all available option values per item per option)

```
item_id
option_id -- not required, but I added since it's easier to figure it out
option_value_id
```

---

`orders` table (stores the orders)

```
order_id
customer_id
order_date
billing_address
delivery_address
```

---

`order_position` table (contains the order positions)

```
order_pos_id
order_id
item_id
quantity
```

---

`order_pos_option` table (contains the options for each order position)

```
order_pos_id
option_id
option_value_id
```

This is quite a generic approach that allows for an undefined number of options and option value that are defined on a per item basis.

If there are not that many options, an alternative would be to go specific, something like this:

---

`colors` table (contains all colors)

```
color_id
name
```

---

`item_available_colors` (available colors per item_id)

```
item_id
color_id
```

---

`sizes` table (contains all sizes)

```
size_id
name
```

---

`item_available_sizes` (available sizes per item_id)

```
item_id
size_id
```

---

`order_position` table (contains the order positions)

```
order_pos_id
order_id
item_id
quantity
color_id
size_id
```

The `item` and `orders` tables stay the same, all others are not needed anymore.

There are lots of other possible variations, this is meant to provide you with a starting point.

Comment: Thank you. I am pretty new to working with RDBMS, so I appreciate the help **very** much.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. I see it's your first question, welcome aboard, also consider answering the questions of others, share you knowledge.